# Append empty character to each entry in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table of countries which has a countryName column consisting country names, where each country name has different name length. I need to make all the names in the column to have the same Length. I have used `UPDATE country SET countryName = Concat(name,'           ');` to add empty character to each entry, but how can I make all the names have the same length?

Thank you,

Comment: Why would you want to do that? This sort of thing should be handled by whatever you're using to display the data.

Comment: Thank you Mat for your kind reply. I am gathering data from many tables, eg. country , prices and network. I need to prepare the data and send it via outlook to my client, eg. Country - Network - Price, when data is being move to outlook, it came not aligned(based on country name length). Thats why I need to make all the countries name length identical.

Comment: 1. Do you still want a *trailing space character* if all the names are set to same length? 2. Do you want to consider length of a max length name as standard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use MySQL [RPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_rpad) AND [LPAD](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_lpad) functions

```
UPDATE country SET countryName = RPAD(name,60,' ');
```

This way ' ' will be appended until size 60 is reached.

Comment: @alkhader Be careful with this. If you have a country name that is longer than 10 characters, it will get truncated, or if there is no country name with more than 10 characters, you will have more spaces to the right than you really need to make all lengths equal. Best to base it on a known maximum length.

Answer (score 1):

This will update the `countryName` field right padded with spaces to the length of the longest `countryName` in the table:

```
UPDATE country a
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT MAX(CHAR_LENGTH(countryName)) AS maxlen
    FROM country
) b
SET a.countryName = RPAD(a.countryName, b.maxlen, ' ')
```